# Creating event calendar application using PHP and other technologies

Tags: php, html, web-applications, web

I want to create an event calendar application similar to the site http://events.stanford.edu/ using PHP and some other technologies. What technologies have been used on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [events.stanford.edu](http://events.stanford.edu) uses two main technologies and one main principle.

The technologies it uses are server-side scripting and a database.  In your case, you could use PHP and MySQL.

The principle the site uses is similar to a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API).  That's not a perfect explanation, but it might put you on the right research path.

Essentially what the application does is when you hit the page, like for [this month](http://events.stanford.edu/2011/March/), it selects all the events from the database and parses them to the page.  It also renders the calendar with links to every day in the month and the next and previous months (e.g. [March 9](http://events.stanford.edu/2011/March/9/), or [April](http://events.stanford.edu/2011/April/)).

There's undoubtedly some magic happening on the server to translate the URLs into understandable queries, but that's something for another handler (like, .htaccess, but that might be a little rough).